Issues with RDS MySQL Blue Green Deployments configuration options in Terraform
I have enabled blue green deployments on MySQL RDS DB - blue_green_update { enabled = true }. It handles some changes fine, like params of aws_db_parameter_group, however, when I tried updating engine version from 8.0.34 to 8.0.36, I got an error: "Error: updating RDS DB Instance: switching over Blue/Green Deployment: waiting for completion: timeout while waiting for state to become 'SWITCHOVER_COMPLETED' (last state: 'AVAILABLE', timeout: 2h14m10.134s)." Does anyone know a workaround or have an advice? Thank you.
My understanding that Terraform doesn't offer any control over the Blue Green Deployment configurations, like setting a timeout period, which what I would have tried, or adding the option of --upgrade-target-storage-config (not relevant, just an example).
